# Two radio buttons can be selected once though i want to select only one

Tags: android, radio-button

I am making an android app and in the application the two radio buttons can be selected once. But I wanted to select only one. What should I code?

```
public class ProfileManagement extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button update;
    private EditText uname, dob, pass;
    private RadioButton male, female;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private String userId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_management);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        userId = intent.getStringExtra("id");

        uname = findViewById(R.id.user);
        dob = findViewById(R.id.date);
        pass = findViewById(R.id.word);
        update = findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        male = findViewById(R.id.radioMale);
        female = findViewById(R.id.radioFe);

        ArrayList<User> list =  dbHelper.readAllInfo(userId, null);

        for (User u : list){

            uname.setText(u.getUserName());
            pass.setText(u.getPassword());
            dob.setText(u.getDateOfBirth());
```

This is the way i check radio button. Is this okay?

```
if(u.getGender() != null){
        if(u.getGender().equals("Male")){

                male.setChecked(true);
            }
            else
            {
                female.setChecked(true);
            }      } }
    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileManagement.this, EditProfile.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", userId);
            startActivity(intent);
        }          });      }  }
```

Comment: you need to use the RadioGroup for the buttons which need to be only 1 selected at time

Answer (score 1):

Utilise radio group like so:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
        android:background="#abf234"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/sound" >
         
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sound"
            android:text="@string/Sound" />
         
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/vibration"
            android:text="@string/Vibration" />
         
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/silent"
            android:text="@string/Silent" />
        
</RadioGroup>
```

and then to check which button has been clicked use the code below:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rGroup, int checkedId) {

        int radioBtnID = rGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        View radioB = rGroup.findViewById(radioBtnID);

        int position = group.indexOfChild(radioB);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

updated code snippet is below. Alternatively, you can try [Spinners](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) Or [RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

```
        if(u.getGender().equals("Male")){

            male.setChecked(true);
            female.setChecked(false); //uncheck female
        }
        else
        {
            female.setChecked(true);
            male.setChecked(false); //uncheck male
        }
```

Comment: Thanks i will correct the code and see whether it works or not

Comment: did it work for you? If so, can you please mark it as the right answer? Small little steps such as upvoting and marking as right answers motivates a ton of people in this community to spend time to find answers that help your fellow programmers. In case it didn't help you, then please do say that also, and also talk about your observations. Else there is no way for this community of programmers to know if you are/were successful to program as you intended.

Comment: Could you please tell if you tried all the three options (1) code snippet (2) RadioGroup and (3) Spinners and still it didn't work for you?